# Lua Bytecode to Lua human "readable"

Tags: lua, bytecode

I just got an script that I want to make some changes and I'm looking for someone to develop me a freelance job to make the loadstring that I will give readable for editing.

The Lua code is like this:

> ### ------------------------- ENGINE -----------------------------
>
> code='\27\76\117\97\81\0\1\4\4\4\8\0\56\0\0\0\64\67\58\92\85\115\101\114\115\92\74\101\

I want it to be turned into a human code. I already searched about the subject and found that there are some tools like `Chuckspy`, `Luadec51` and `Unluac` that can do this job. Anyway, I never programmed before in lua and got no compiler knowledge to perform that.

I'm looking for someone to help me, I have no idea how I'll do it.
Thanks anyway

The link of two archive:

http://www.4shared.com/file/uQguRL4D/Avani_Dice_Script_1.html

http://www.4shared.com/file/FSLbD9tA/Avani_Dice_Script_2.html

Comment: Please don't add answers to ask new questions. If you have a new question, ask a new one. SO is **not** a forum.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`luac -l` will print out the Lua bytecode in human-readable form. With a basic understanding of Lua's instruction format, this is fairly easy to manually turn into source code.

As with other languages, automatic decompilers will rarely produce source code which is useful for understanding or editing the code.